# Extract 5th Business Date from sysdate

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm looking to extract the 5th Business Date data from database. Looking for pure 5th Business Date, no other business requirement like Holiday or New Year day.

Looking to extract 07/03/2022 from dual table using Oracle PL/SQL

| Date | Day | Requirement |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1/03/2022 | Tuesday | 1BD |
| 2/03/2022 | Wednesday | 2BD |
| 3/03/2022 | Thursday | 3BD |
| 4/03/2022 | Friday | 4BD |
| 5/03/2022 | Saturday | Weekend |
| 6/03/2022 | Sunday | Weekend |
| 7/03/2022 | Monday | 5BD |
| 8/03/2022 | Tuesday | 6BD |
| 9/03/2022 | Wednesday | 7BD |

Comment: What do you mean "extract 07/03/2022 from dual table". Dual table is a dummy table u don t extract anything from it. Are u trying to get 5th business day date for any month (or sysdate month)?

Comment: @ToniAntunović amended my question

Answer (score 1):

This is how I understood it.

Today is Thursday, 24.03.2022. It means that 5th business day looking *backwards* is Friday, 18.03.2022.

```
SQL> with test (datum, day) as
  2    -- calendar
  3    (select
  4                    trunc(sysdate) - &&par_number_of_days * 2 + level - 1,
  5            to_char(trunc(sysdate) - &&par_number_of_days * 2 + level - 1, 'dy',
  6                    'nls_date_language = english')
  7     from dual
  8     connect by level <= (&&par_number_of_days * 2) + 1
  9    ),
 10  only_working_days as
 11    -- remove weekends
 12    (select datum,
 13            day,
 14            row_number() over (order by datum desc) rn
 15     from test
 16     where day not in ('sat', 'sun')
 17    )
 18  select datum, day, rn
 19  from only_working_days
 20  where rn = &&par_number_of_days;
Enter value for par_number_of_days: 5

DATUM      DAY         RN
---------- --- ----------
18.03.2022 fri          5
```

Or, 13th business day backwards is 08.03.2022:

```
SQL> undefine par_number_of_days
SQL> /
Enter value for par_number_of_days: 13

DATUM      DAY         RN
---------- --- ----------
08.03.2022 tue         13

SQL>
```

---

If it  is, on the other hand, related to period since 1st of current, month, then

```
SQL> with test (datum, day) as
  2    (select trunc(sysdate, 'mm') + level - 1,
  3            to_char(trunc(sysdate, 'mm') + level - 1, 'dy', 'nls_date_language = english')
  4     from dual
  5     connect by level <= trunc(sysdate) - trunc(sysdate, 'mm') + 1
  6    ),
  7  only_working_days as
  8    -- remove weekends
  9    (select datum,
 10            day,
 11            row_number() over (order by datum) rn
 12     from test
 13     where day not in ('sat', 'sun')
 14    )
 15  select datum, day, rn
 16  from only_working_days
 17  where rn = &par_number_of_days;
Enter value for par_number_of_days: 5

DATUM      DAY         RN
---------- --- ----------
07.03.2022 mon          5

SQL> /
Enter value for par_number_of_days: 13

DATUM      DAY         RN
---------- --- ----------
17.03.2022 thu         13

SQL>
```

Comment: He is only trying to find 5th  business day date for current month, for today the result should be 8.3.2022.

Comment: @Toni, "from sysdate" is hardly "first of current month". Sysdate = *today*. At least - and as I said - that's how I understood the question. Anyway: this is *how to*, shouldn't be too difficult to adjust it.

Comment: look the comments under his question

Comment: @Toni, comments don't help much, but sample table *might*. I edited the answer and added that option as well (way simpler than previous).

Comment: This is very inefficient and only works for a single input value.

Answer (score 1):

The 5th business day will always be 7 days ahead, since there will be 5 weekdays and 2 weekend days, so the simplest solution is:

```sql
SELECT TRUNC(SYSDATE) + INTERVAL '7' DAYS
FROM   DUAL
```

More generally, if you want to add a number of business days to a date then you can calculate it using:

```sql
start_date
+ FLOOR(bd/5) * INTERVAL '7' DAY -- Full weeks
+ MOD(bd, 5) -- Part week
+ CASE
  WHEN start_date - TRUNC(start_date, 'IW') + MOD(bd, 5) >= 5
  THEN 2
  WHEN start_date - TRUNC(start_date, 'IW') + MOD(bd, 5) < 0
  THEN -2
  ELSE 0
  END -- Adjust for weekend
```

---

For example, given the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (start_date, bd) AS
  SELECT TRUNC(SYSDATE), LEVEL - 11 FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 21
UNION ALL
  SELECT DATE '2022-03-01', 5 FROM DUAL;
```

Then:

```sql
SELECT start_date,
       bd,
       start_date
       + FLOOR(bd/5) * INTERVAL '7' DAY -- Full weeks
       + MOD(bd, 5) -- Part week
       + CASE
         WHEN start_date - TRUNC(start_date, 'IW') + MOD(bd, 5) >= 5
         THEN 2
         WHEN start_date - TRUNC(start_date, 'IW') + MOD(bd, 5) < 0
         THEN -2
         ELSE 0
         END -- Adjust for weekend
         AS adjusted_business_day
FROM   table_name;
```

Outputs:

> | START_DATE | BD | ADJUSTED_BUSINESS_DAY |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | 2022-03-24 00:00:00 (THU) | -10 | 2022-03-10 00:00:00 (THU) |
> | 2022-03-24 00:00:00 (THU) | -9 | 2022-03-04 00:00:00 (FRI) |
> | 2022-03-24 00:00:00 (THU) | -8 | 2022-03-07 00:00:00 (MON) |
> | 2022-03-24 00:00:00 (THU) | -7 | 2022-03-08 00:00:00 (TUE) |
> | 2022-03-24 00:00:00 (THU) | -6 | 2022-03-09 00:00:00 (WED) |
> | 2022-03-24 00:00:00 (THU) | -5 | 2022-03-17 00:00:00 (THU) |
> | 2022-03-24 00:00:00 (THU) | -4 | 2022-03-11 00:00:00 (FRI) |
> | 2022-03-24 00:00:00 (THU) | -3 | 2022-03-14 00:00:00 (MON) |
> | 2022-03-24 00:00:00 (THU) | -2 | 2022-03-15 00:00:00 (TUE) |
> | 2022-03-24 00:00:00 (THU) | -1 | 2022-03-16 00:00:00 (WED) |
> | 2022-03-24 00:00:00 (THU) | 0 | 2022-03-24 00:00:00 (THU) |
> | 2022-03-24 00:00:00 (THU) | 1 | 2022-03-25 00:00:00 (FRI) |
> | 2022-03-24 00:00:00 (THU) | 2 | 2022-03-28 00:00:00 (MON) |
> | 2022-03-24 00:00:00 (THU) | 3 | 2022-03-29 00:00:00 (TUE) |
> | 2022-03-24 00:00:00 (THU) | 4 | 2022-03-30 00:00:00 (WED) |
> | 2022-03-24 00:00:00 (THU) | 5 | 2022-03-31 00:00:00 (THU) |
> | 2022-03-24 00:00:00 (THU) | 6 | 2022-04-01 00:00:00 (FRI) |
> | 2022-03-24 00:00:00 (THU) | 7 | 2022-04-04 00:00:00 (MON) |
> | 2022-03-24 00:00:00 (THU) | 8 | 2022-04-05 00:00:00 (TUE) |
> | 2022-03-24 00:00:00 (THU) | 9 | 2022-04-06 00:00:00 (WED) |
> | 2022-03-24 00:00:00 (THU) | 10 | 2022-04-07 00:00:00 (THU) |
> | 2022-03-01 00:00:00 (TUE) | 5 | 2022-03-08 00:00:00 (TUE) |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=189fc5764e700e063e6e0a594de26fbb)*